# EF Core Fluent API Null Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, fluent, ef-core-2.2

I have the following tables : Products, Users and ProductApproval. Whenever user create a new product, the ProductApproval will have a new record with the product ID and a null ApprovedByUserId because it is not approve yet. User can have many ProductApproval but Product only can have one ProductApproval.

The structure is like this:

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductApproval> ProductApprovals { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
       ProductApprovals = new Collection<ProductApproval>();
    }
}
```

Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductApproval ProductApproval { get; set; }
}
```

ProductApproval.cs

```
public class ProductApproval
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
   public int? ProductId { get; set; }

   public virtual User User { get ;set; }
   public int? ApprovedByUserId { get; set; }

}
```

DataContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.ProductApprovals)
   .WithOne(pa => pa.User)
   .HasForeignKey(pa => pa.ApprovedByUserId)
   .IsRequired(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
   .HasOne(p => p.ProductApproval)
   .WithOne(pa => pa.Product)
   .HasForeignKey<ProductApproval>(pa => pa.ProductId);
```

I already declared the foreign key ApprovedByUserId as nullable, but i still get the following error when i insert a record into productapprovals : 
**MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysite`.`productapprovals`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ProductApprovals_Users_ApprovedByUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`ApprovedByUserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT)**

Please advice is there any place i did wrong

Comment: The configuration is ok. The exception means you are passing non existing non null `ApprovedByUserId ` value.

Comment: Ivan, what do you mean by non existing non null? I tried passing null or 0 both also return the same error.

Comment: `null` should work. any other value is treated as "existing", i.e. there must be a `User` record with such "Id" value. Make sure you also have `User` navigation property set to `null` because it has priority over FK property. In other words, setting both `User` and `ApprovedByUserId` to `null` should work.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, it is working fine now. Appreciate for your help